# Get specific content from SP List with JS

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm pretty new to using the SP.JS, and I'm stuck on trying to pull information from a list. This is what I want to do: I am creating a link hit counter that will update the hit column whenever a link is clicked on, along with keeping track of the href of that link. I currently have the script working perfectly writing to a table, However, instead of using a table, I want to write to a Sharepoint list. One of the tricky parts is that I need to search the "href" column of the sharepoint list to see if the clicked on href already exists, if it does, then update the corresponding hit field. If it doesn't exist, then it had to add the href list.

Right now I"m having trouble accessing the SP list, and am getting an error. Here's the current code:

```
    var siteurl = 'urlofsite'
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteurl);
    var HrefList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('HrefTracker');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    var collListItem = HrefList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        


    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
        var listItemInfo = '';
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            listItemInfo += '\nHref: ' + oList.get_item('href');
        }

        alert(listItemInfo.toString());
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Right now I"m getting an error in a SP ajax script: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined. At this point, I just want to see if it's actually pulling any information from the column and alerting it to see what it is. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default **SharePoint ExecuteQuery does not load** all properties of an item. We need to load those properties explicitly.

Use following syntax to load your custom column.

```
clientContext.load(collListItem,'Include(href)');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```